# Pantalla de carga en Angular 6

Tags: angular

Tengo una aplicación en Angular donde trae de una base de datos mucha información (más de 6000 elementos). Cuando el usuario pica un botón se muestran todos esos elementos (no tienen que ser paginados), eso lo hago con un *ngFor, el asunto es que tarda en cargar todos esos elementos. ¿Hay alguna manera de que mientas lo cargue aparezca una pantalla de carga o simplemente un  que diga cargando o algo así?

Comment: Encontré un ejemplo [puedes revisarlo aquí](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/22/angular2-using-custom-loader-spinner-as-service-in-angular-2-application/) , espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Buenas, Angular o AngularJS?

Comment: Recomiendo que puedas paginar esos elementos en backend  ya que el DOM se ve muy afectado al insertar tantos elementos en pantalla, que aunque utilices un loader, la experiencia de usuario no sera la mas deseada.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear un `div` el cual le agregas un `*ngIf` el cual muestre un (cargando.., gitf o animacion) mientras se cargan tus datos. Seria algo asi.

```
<div *ngIf="!user">
  Cargando...
</div>
```

y tu otro `div` con los datos

```
<div *ngIf='user'>
  <img src="{{ user.avatar }}" alt="">
  <h2>{{ user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name }}</h2>
</div>
```